# Give a multiple choice test

Tags: code-golf

I present to you a test! Your test is to test. The test is to test the testee with tests a tester gives you, in the shor**test** amount of code. Specifically, you will give a multiple choice test that you have recieved as input.

In this challenge, you must take an input like this:

```
1. Our site is called Programming Puzzles & Code ________.
A: Debugging
*B: Golf
C: Hockey
D: Programming
2. What is the *most* popular tag on our site?
A: [debug]
B: [program]
*C: [code-golf]
D: [number]
E: [c++]
3. We are part of the ________ Exchange network.
*A: Stack
B: Code
C: Programmer
D: Hockey
4. Is this the first question?
A: Yes
*B: No
5. Is this the last question?
*A: Yes
B: No
```

And here is an example of the test being taken:

```
1. Our site is called Programming Puzzles & Code ________.
A: Debugging
B: Golf
C: Hockey
D: Programming
answer: B
correct!

2. What is the *most* popular tag on our site?
A: [debug]
B: [program]
C: [code-golf]
D: [number]
E: [c++]
answer: C
correct!

3. We are part of the ________ Exchange network.
A: Stack
B: Code
C: Programmer
D: Hockey
answer: B
incorrect! the answer was A

4. Is this the first question?
A: Yes
B: No
answer: B
correct!

5. Is this the last question?
A: Yes
B: No
answer: B
incorrect! the answer was A

overview:
3 correct, 2 incorrect (60%)

3. We are part of the ________ Exchange network.
you chose B: Code
the answer was A: Stack

5. Is this the last question?
you chose B: No
the answer was A: Yes
```

Formal specification:

- Input

  - If a line begins with a number followed by a dot and a space, it is a question with that number. Numbers will always start from 1 and go up 1 each question.
  - If a line begins with an optional asterisk, a letter, a colon, and then a space, it is an answer. Answers will also always be sequential. There will be only one correct answer per question.
  - A line will not begin in any other way than the previously mentioned ways.
  - Input may be accepted in any way (reading from a file, stdin, etc.) but must not be hardcoded into your program.
- Output (test-taking phase)

  - First, print out each question sequentially. Print the question and its answers as recieved in input, but do not print the asterisk indicating correct answers.
  - Then, print a newline and `"answer: "`. Wait for user input. User input will always correspond to an answer.
  - If the correct answer (the one with an asterisk) is the same as the one the user input, output `"correct!"`. Otherwise, output `"incorrect! the answer was " + correct_letter`.
  - Separate each question with a blank line, then repeat the previous output steps until there are no more questions.
- Output (overview phase)

  - Print `"overview: "` and then a newline.
  - Print `"{number of correct answers} correct, {incorrect answers} incorrect ({percent correct, rounded to the nearest whole number}%)"` (of course substituting the phrases in curly braces with their respective values). Then print a blank line for spacing.
  - Now, for each question that was wrong, print the question (not its answers), then on a new line `"you chose " + answer_you_chose`, and on another line `"the answer was " + correct_answer`. Separate each wrong answer's overview with a blank line.
- In order to reduce cheating by interpreting things literally, when given the same output here, and the same input in the test-taking phase, your program must output exactly the same thing as the sample output.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf); shortest code wins! (And gets an A+ (green checkmark)!)

Comment: Nice challenge, but I wish the sample test to contain possibly tricky situations, like `\d\. `, `\w: ` and `\*` in the middle of questions/answers. (For example currently the `*` can be eliminated with `y/*//`, while the correct way is lengthy as `s/^\*//`.)

Comment: Do we need to allow line continuation? I mean, will there be lines not starting with “1. ” or “A: ”? If yes, please include such cases in the sample test.

Comment: @manatwork (first comment) Ok, editing (second comment) no, you do not. I will clarify.

Comment: So how are you going to test this test test?

Comment: @JoeZ. Umm... not sure what you mean... I did provide a test test case for the test to test your tester

Comment: That is true. My bad.

Comment: and the end, when printing out incorrect answers - what do you want printed if the user entered a non-option? Like say the user entered 'Q' to any of the questions above?

Comment: @Mtn I have specified that you can assume they will not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Perl 5, 279

```pl
$y=correct;@w=(the,$n=answer,was);map{s/^\*((.+?):.+)/$a=$1/me;print"$_$n: ";chop($@=<>);print$@eq($l=$2)?++$d&&"$y!

":(/^\d.+/,$o.=$&,/^$@.+/m,$o.="
you chose: $&
@w $a

")&&"in$y! @w $l

"}@_=split/(?=^\d)/m,join"",<>;printf"overview:
$d $y, %d in$y (%d%)

$o",@_-$d,$d/@_*100
```

*Note: The newlines are required for output formatting.*

Every time I think I can't golf it any more, I learn something new! It's slowly becoming more punctuation than legible text... I think that's a good thing?

Usage: `perl -e '...' test.txt` or `perl test.pl test.txt`.

If you choose an option not presented in the list, you will get incorrect output in the overview (it will say `you chose: 1. Our site is called Programming Puzzles & Code ________.` for example).

[Example run](http://showterm.io/13c98a3e82872a76461f4)

Comment: Kindly show an example of input and output.

Comment: @DavidCarraher added an updated link to output via [showterm.io](http://showterm.io/13c98a3e82872a76461f4). Thought that would be marginally better than static output, although it still doesn't capture it exactly the same as it is in the terminal.

Comment: That gives a fairly good view of how your program works.

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica 144

This may be an invalid attempt. I separated the question from each answer in the input. I also indicated the correct answer by a letter in a separate field, rather than an asterisk before the alternative.

Anyway...

**The Data**

```
questions={{{"\n1. Our site is called Programming Puzzles & Code ________.\n","A: Bugging\n","B: Golf\n","C: Hockey\n","D: Programming\n"},"B"},{{"\n2. What is the most popular tag on our site? \n","A: [debug]\n","B: [program]\n","C: [code golf]\n","D: [number]\n"},"C"},{{"\n3. We are part of the _______ Exchange network. \n","A: Stack\n","B: Code\n","C: Programmer\n","D: Hockey\n"},"A"},{{"\n4. Is this the first question? \n","A: Yes\n","B: No\n"},"B"},{{"\n5. Is this the last question? \n","A: Yes\n","B: No\n"},"A"}};
```

**Code**

An answer to each question is entered through a dialog box.
Questions, answers, and feedback are printed.

```
f@x_:=
Print[If[((r=ChoiceDialog[Print[""<>#,"\nanswer: "];""<>#,StringTake[Rest@#,1]])==#2),
r<>"\ncorrect!", r<>"\nincorrect, the answer is "<>#2]&@@x]
```

**Test**

```
f /@ questions
```

[image: dialog choice]

Comment: wow, impressive! the input is not in the correct form though... still, that is very remarkable for the brevity of the code and how much it does!

Comment: Thanks. Massaging the input string into a Mathematica-friendly structure is of course possible, but it would have hidden the elegance underlying the present, ineligible solution.

Comment: Nice.  Four characters shorter: `g@{a_,b_}:=Print[If[(r=ChoiceDialog[Print[""<>a,"\nanswer: "];""<>a,Rest@a~StringTake~1])==b,r<>"\ncorrect!",r<>"\nincorrect, the answer is "<>b]]`

Comment: And save one more by using `Print@If[...]` rather than `Print[If[...]]`.

Answer (score 2):

**Java - 1210**

```
int i,o;String q;String[]s={"1. Our site is called Programming Puzzles & Code ________.\n","2. What is the most popular tag on our site?\n","3. We are part of the ________ Exchange network.\n","4. Is this the first question?\n","5. Is this the last question?\n"},b={"B","C","A","B","A"},p=new String[5];String[][]a={{"A: Debugging\n","B: Golf\n","C: Hockey\n","D: Programming\n","answer: "},{"A: [debug]\n","B: [program]\n","C: [code-golf]\n","D: [number]\n","E: [c++]\n","answer: "},{"A: Stack\n","B: Code\n","C: Programmer\n","D: Hockey\n","answer: "},{"A: Yes\n","B: No\n","answer: "},{"A: Yes\n","B: No\n","answer: "}};java.util.Map<String,Integer>m=new java.util.HashMap(){{put("A",0);put("B",1);put("C",2);put("D",3);put("E",4);}};java.util.Scanner u=new java.util.Scanner(System.in);for(i=0;i<5;i++){q=s[i];for(o=0;o<a[i].length;)q+=a[i][o++];System.out.print(q);if(b[i].equals(p[i]=u.nextLine()))q="correct!";else q="incorrect! the answer was "+b[i];System.out.println(q+"\n");}q="";o=0;for(i=0;i<5;i++)if(b[i].equals(p[i]))o++;else q+=s[i]+"you chose "+a[i][m.get(p[i])]+"the answer was "+a[i][m.get(b[i])]+"\n";System.out.println("overview:\n"+o+" correct, "+(5-o)+" incorrect ("+o*100/5+"%)\n\n"+q);
```

formatted: 1980

```
String[] s = {"1. Our site is called Programming Puzzles & Code ________.\n",
        "2. What is the most popular tag on our site?\n",
        "3. We are part of the ________ Exchange network.\n",
        "4. Is this the first question?\n",
        "5. Is this the last question?\n"};
    String[][] a = {
        {"A: Debugging\n", "B: Golf\n", "C: Hockey\n", "D: Programming\n", "answer: "},
        {"A: [debug]\n", "B: [program]\n", "C: [code-golf]\n", "D: [number]\n", "E: [c++]\n", "answer: "},
        {"A: Stack\n", "B: Code\n", "C: Programmer\n", "D: Hockey\n", "answer: "},
        {"A: Yes\n", "B: No\n", "answer: "},
        {"A: Yes\n", "B: No\n", "answer: "}};

    java.util.Map<String, Integer> m = new java.util.HashMap<String, Integer>() {
        {
            put("A", 0);
            put("B", 1);
            put("C", 2);
            put("D", 3);
            put("E", 4);
        }
    };
    String[] b = {"B", "C", "A", "B", "A"};
    String[] p = new String[5];
    java.util.Scanner u = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
    String q;
    int i;
    int o;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        q = s[i];
        for (o = 0; o < a[i].length;) {
            q += a[i][o++];
        }
        System.out.print(q);
        if (b[i].equals(p[i] = u.nextLine())) {
            q = "correct!";
        } else {
            q = "incorrect! the answer was " + b[i];
        }
        System.out.println(q + "\n");
    }
    q = "";
    o = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        if (b[i].equals(p[i])) {
            o++;
        } else {
            q += s[i] + "you chose " + a[i][m.get(p[i])] + "the answer was " + a[i][m.get(b[i])] + "\n";
        }
    }
    System.out.println("overview:\n" + " correct, " + (5 - o) + " incorrect (" + o * 100 / 5 + "%)\n\n" + q);
```

This certainly won’t be the shortest but it is all self-contained

Answer (score 0):

### Haskell, 598

```
import System.Environment
import System.IO
n=putStrLn
p=putStr
d#s=p$show d++s
v&(m:a)=n m>>q[]""a>>= \(r,(s,t))->n s>>n"">>b v m t&r
(r,w,s)&[]=n"overview:">>r#" correct, ">>w#" incorrect (">>((100*r)`div`(r+w))#"%)\n">>mapM_ n s
b(r,w,s)m t|null t=(r+1,w,s)|1<3=(r,w+1,s++"":m:t)
q u c(('*':a):r)=q u a(a:r)
q u c(a@(o:':':_):r)=n a>>q(([o],a):u)c r
q u c r=p"answer: ">>hFlush stdout>>(\i->(r,a(maybe i id$lookup i u)c))`fmap`getLine
a j c|j==c=("correct!",[])|1<3=("incorrect! the answer was "++[head c],["you choose "++j,"the answer was "++c])
main=getArgs>>=readFile.head>>=((0,0,[])&).lines
```

Way longer than I'd like. It's set wiki so have at it!

Alas, we lose 32 characters to flushing stdout. Another 38 characters could be saved if the test script were read from a fixed file named "t" rather than specified on the command line.

When run on the input given in the question:

```
& runhaskell 15961-Tester.hs 15961-test.txt 
1. Our site is called Programming Puzzles & Code ________.
A: Debugging
B: Golf
C: Hockey
D: Programming
answer: B
correct!

2. What is the *most* popular tag on our site?
A: [debug]
B: [program]
C: [code-golf]
D: [number]
E: [c++]
answer: C
correct!

3. We are part of the ________ Exchange network.
A: Stack
B: Code
C: Programmer
D: Hockey
answer: B
incorrect! the answer was A

4. Is this the first question?
A: Yes
B: No
answer: B
correct!

5. Is this the last question?
A: Yes
B: No
answer: B
incorrect! the answer was A

overview:
3 correct, 2 incorrect (60%)

3. We are part of the ________ Exchange network.
you choose B: Code
the answer was A: Stack

5. Is this the last question?
you choose B: No
the answer was A: Yes
```